# How would I intuitively know to use a function of x or y?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm doing fine with solving solids of revolutions using disk, washers and shells, but often times I get confused with making the problem a $f(x)$ or $f(y)$.

I think when one is using disk and washers, you use $f(x)$ if you are rotating the solid around the $x-axis$ and $f(y)$ if the solid is rotating around the $y-axis$.  But when using shells, how do I pick which to use?

He is a sample problem that I drew out graphically and felt like I could use $f(x)$ or $f(y)$ but the solution shown only shows the options of using $f(x)$

`Set up the integral to find the volume of the solid created by revolving the region bounded by` $y=x^2$, $y=0$, and $x=3$, `about the y-axis, using the method of shells. DO NOT EVALUATE THE INTEGRAL!`

I guess is my confusion is when looking at the functions graphically it seems like I can get a value by examining the function at both $x, y$, but clearly that's not correct.

Do you have any advice for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If rotating around the $y$-axis, use $f(x)$, if rotating around the $x$ axis, use $f(y)$[image]

When rotating around the $y$ axis the equation for integration is $$2\pi \int_{a}^{b} x f_h(x) dx$$ where $f_h(x)$ gives the height of the function.   Conversely, when rotating around the $x$ axis, [image]

We see that we must put the height in terms of $y$. As a result the formula changes to
$$2\pi \int_{a_y}^{b_y} f_h(y) dy$$ and we must also remember to change $ a \to a_y$ and $ b \to b_y$

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this!